# Android: updating the screen during computer controlled UI changes

Tags: android, refresh, screen, delay

I've checked the other questions asked here and didn't succeed in implementing the solutions.  My application uses controls, not drawing on the canvas.  Basically this sums up my issue: -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn5 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn6 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn7 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
 //blah blah blah
    btn1.requestFocus();
    wait(100);
    btn2.requestFocus();
    wait(100);
    btn3.requestFocus();
    wait(100);
    btn3.setChecked(true);
    wait(100);
    btn4.requestFocus();
    wait(100);
    btn4.setChecked(true);
    wait(100);
    btn5.requestFocus();
    wait(100);
    btn6.requestFocus();
    wait(100);
    btn6.setChecked(true);
    wait(100);
    btn7.requestFocus();
    wait(100);
 //etc
}
```

The point being the computer animates the moving to a the buttons and checking them so the user can see what it is doing.  So, my issue is, what goes in my wait() method that will pause for 100ms and also update the screen, and the focus?  Any help really appreciated, cheers Jonathan.

Solution applies, thanks Andrew :)

```
int timerCounterInterval = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ToggleButton btn1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final ToggleButton btn2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
// more btns
    timerCounterInterval = 0; //reset, for each pass of automation
    setFocus(btn1);
    setFocus(btn2);
    setChecked(btn2);
// tidy up
    timerCounterInterval++;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            btn2.clearFocus(); //whatever button that had the focus last
            }
    }, 100*(timerCounterInterval));
// etc - note any code from here will execute *before* the above timer
}   

public void setFocus(final ToggleButton btn) {
    timerCounterInterval++;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            btn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); //eww, messy i know
            btn.requestFocus();
            btn.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); 
        } 
    }, 100*timerCounterInterval);
}

public void setChecked(final ToggleButton btn) {
    timerCounterInterval++;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            btn.setChecked(true);
        } 
    }, 100*timerCounterInterval);
}
```

Hope this helps other people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest you look into the [Handle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) object and in particular the [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method. That way you can keep everything on the UI thread while not causing the thread to actually be tied up in an animate method. This also keeps the Activity from giving that dreaded this-application-is-not-responding message.

In fact, simply wrapping your calls to the control's setters in a runnable and passing them to postDelayed should be enough to update the GUI controls.

[Update]
As an example per your comments you might try something like this. I haven't actually tested this but I think the idea is still there...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ToggleButton btn1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final ToggleButton btn2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    // more btns

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    /* tell the handler run these bits after 1 sec, 2 sec, 3 sec, ect... */
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { void run () { btn1.requestFocus(); } }, 1000);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { void run () { btn2.requestFocus(); } }, 2000);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { void run () { btn2.setChecked(true); } }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I saw that solution and got stuck on implementing. I saw the next automatic step was the one within the handle object, so I'm assuming I can pass a command such as "btn1.requestFocus()" as a parameter. I'm new to Java so I'm lost on the syntax:
private static void wait(int ms, what_goes_here?) {
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 
my what_goes_here get called here somehow!; 
              } 
         }, ms);      
    }

Can you please fill in the gaps?  (sorry for bad layout, cant embed code neatly)

Comment: It's not working. I decided to be a bit smarter, and changed my "wait" to a "setFocus" as this is now what it is.  So my main code is "setFocus(btn1)" instead of "btn1.requestFocus();wait(100)" - my setFocus() method is: 
public void setFocus(final ToggleButton btn) {
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
public void run() {btn.requestFocus();} }, 100);
}
Only, it doesn't work. Method returns instantly and the user can't see the focus moving from button to button and getting ticked (I have a duplicate method for setting the switch).  Help please?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example but I do wonder if 100 is a bit short. With only 1/10 of a second per "frame" the "animation" might be happening faster than you can see it. My example uses whole seconds just to be clear.

Comment: Yea, thanks for that suggestion.  I tried with 10 second delays :P multiplied by calling it about 10 times would of shown the delay.  I tried your new code, it also returned immediately..  I've also noticed its impossible to change the string of a TextView more than once in a method and hope to have it update - as I couldn't fake focus moving and checking, I went to update a TextView to "Please wait" and back to an empty string, using Thread.sleep() [i know, i know] for pseudo pause inbetween - and it wouldn't update either, even after being invalidated -.-  Can't get the UI to force update :(

Comment: Ok, I'm getting smarter :o
Your advice was correct and worked (sorry my bad). Thing is though, I need this to run from an OnClick handler, and as 99.9% of the time it will be launched from a screen touch, it won't show focus (which is why it wasn't working for my until I used the D-Pad).  So, is there another function tied to a Button that shows the focus?  Also, can I prevent user input during this time?  Sorry for hijacking my own thread with different questions, but they sort of relate back to the OP.  I'll edit my OP once I have a working solution too!!

Comment: Right! All working!!  This is still dummy code, for instance I save the checked state of all my ToggleButton before the animation kicks in, so I can restore them in case the user is tapping the screen while I'm animating. That restore is done in my "tidy up" timer.  Thanks for your quick responses Andrew, cheers.  By the way, if you want to see what this implementation was for, then let me know - I'm rather proud of it as my first application!